# Can't retrieve keychain passwords while in SSH session

Tags: command-line, password, keychain, ssh

I can't get `security` (the command line interface for the keychain) to retrieve passwords with `security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga <name>` over SSH. It only seems to work in physical console sessions - is this actually intended behaviour?

For example, in a normal console session the above command retrieves the password without any problems. SSH to localhost and run it again though and it returns an empty string.

I need the ability to login over SSH and run a script that draws a password down from the keychain for authentication; am I right in thinking Apple have shipped a command line client that breaks in SSH sessions or have I missed something?

Comment: Agreed, that other question basically covers it. This is *so* poor from Apple though. It's like they never considered the obvious use case for `security` was scripting - you have to put in a password to unlock the keychain before this command does anything thereby invalidating the point of using the keychain in the first place.. Not to mention there's 0 in the way of `stdout` for this so you're left thinking you've misconfigured the Keychain item you're trying to retrieve after fiddling with it for *hours*.

Comment: they seem to have fixed this

Comment: @code_monk not for me. Are you able to retrieve passwords with `security` in an SSH session? I'm running the latest version of Mac OS (10.12.5) and still have to be in a console session for it to work.

Comment: yes i am. i'm on 10.12.4. Maybe it has to do with the fact i've authenticated with an RSA key, and have turned password auth off?